# OS X: Run my application automatically right after installing this .pkg file

Tags: macos

I have developed a mac application and using Product->Archive->Share in Xcode to create a .pkg file and will be submitting to Appstore. I would like to run my application automatically right after installing this .pkg file doing this way. I know using PackageMaker, it is possible to write pre and post scripts. But, Appstore is not accepting any .pkg file which are created using PackageMaker, so i'm using Product->Archive->Share in Xcode to create pkg file.

Could someone advise how can i run my application automatically right after installing this .pkg file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to be able to do this. Part of the point of the App Store is that there's a uniform, consistent installation experience—the app downloads, installs silently, then shows up in LaunchPad for you to run if you want to.

Remember when getting Xcode from the App Store used to mean you got an app called "Install Xcode.app" in /Applications, and then you had to run that installer? That confused half of Xcode's users, who are about as technically savvy a user base as any app is likely to have, and it's from Apple, and even they couldn't get around the problem by auto-launching "Install Xcode.app".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. So, are you saying it is not possible to do via Xcode Archive->Share and also Apple don't accept such way to do. Am i right? Please help.

Comment: Right on both counts. It is not possible to do via the simple Xcode Archive Organizer mechanism. It is possible to do in other ways, but Apple will not accept your package if you do so.

Comment: Hi abarnert, can you tell more about those "other ways"? I'm trying to achieve this by using PackageMaker - adding a post install action to open the app automatically but somehow, the app is not running automatically on first install. However, if I tried to remove the app and reinstall again the app runs automatically...

Comment: The post install action is the way to go, but the details of getting it right are tricky (and ever-changing, and I'm not at all up to date on them), so you might want to use a third-party installer generator that takes care of it for you, or at least run such a generator and see what it generates.